# What is the cheapest embedded platform for 2 way wireless comms?

Tags: embedded, wireless

I want to build a project that has 2 embedded controllers that talk wirelessly to command a relay and receive temp data.  I like Arduino, but when you start adding up the shield for the zigbee, and the module the price starts getting up there.  Is there a cheaper option, without having to make my own pcb's and such?  Range needs to be at least 100ft.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want bi directional, if so this may not help, but there are a number of receivers and transmitters like this one

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532

(and the transmitter that goes with it)

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532

or a transceiver http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10153

under $5 or $10 each.  arduinos are quite pricy as well something like this

http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-t2012

is off the shelf, about $3 a board and in the performance range as an arduino, probably uses less power.

get the ez430 stick http://www.ti.com/ez430 or get one of the launchpad boards http://www.ti.com/launchpadwiki and described somewhere in that wiki is the part number for the wee bitty header pins.  here is the part number

The part number for the right angle connector is
mill-max  850-10-006-20-001000

you shouldnt have to do that though you can remove the bank of two pin jumpers on the launchpad board and use wire jumpers to get from the host side to the right pins on the target board, should only need four wires.

Anyway I have a pair of those transmitter/receiver modules just have never actually tried them.  Maybe I should.  I did recently play with the nordic modules

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/691

super easy to use, well okay, they dont just come up and pair like the xbee.  And like the xbee they are in the same price range.

I know that links are discouraged at StackOverflow, not sure there is a better way to put this answer than to use links to the products being talked about.

Comment: Yes the Launchpad looks very cool for $5.  There is even a wireless/LCD addon for $20.  I will take a look.

Comment: duh, thats right, I never tried those boards, out of sight out of mind.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your cheapest option is to get an Arduino, like breadboard - duino or whatever and get breakout boards for your wireless chips.  You can get the wireless zigbee breakout boards pretty cheaply and you don't need to incur the extra cost of a shield, which I agree is too high.

Answer (score -1):

For a 2015 update, the original Launchpad based on MSP430G2553 is $10. An offbrand *ino on eBay is $7.

Now the Maker community is using various spins of the HC06 Bluetooth module, $5-10 on eBay, and there is all kinds of docs and SW on the Web.

A detailed tutorial: http://www.instructables.com/id/Add-bluetooth-to-your-Arduino-project-ArduinoHC-06/

A $15 combo is quite doable, and 100ft line-of-site as well.